# Trying to integrate $\iint_D x^4\tan(x)+3y^2 \,dA$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to integrate $\iint_D x^4\tan(x)+3y^2\, dA$ in domain $D=\{(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x^2+y^2\le4, y\ge0\}$.

Domain is simple enough; half circle of radius 2 over $x$ axis. Converting to polar coordinates doesn't seem an option, considering the complexity of the integral. Integrating normally leads to nowhere, though :

$$\int_{-2}^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} x^4\tan(x)+3y^2 \,dy\,dx$$
$$\vdots$$
$$\int_{-2}^2 \sqrt{4-x^2}x^4\tan(x)+(\sqrt{4-x^2})^3 \,dx$$

I'm taking a calculus II course this summer and am not particularly skilled and this is part of our homework. Can anyone please help me find a solution to this?

Thanks so much !

Comment: Hint: See any symmetry with $x^4\tan x$?

Comment: Somewhat, it would be antisymmetric around y axis, but I'm not sure how I can exploit this, since I integrate only aboxe x. Should I integrate above and under x, I understand this would sum up to 0, though. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: But $\tan(x)$ isn't defined on $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and it is $<2$. I suppose you have yourself an improper integral.

Comment: Oh, I'm dumb, I see it now. I only wonder how on earth I was supposed to know that tan(x) is antisymmetric around y axis. Guess I need some more practice. Alright, thanks !

Comment: Yeah, the important observation here is that the first term in the integrand is odd. There's an important property about integrating odd functions over symmetric intervals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: The integral of $x^4\tan x$ vanishes. (Why?)

Comment: Why? Because it is antisymmetric around y axis and thus sums up to 0. How was I suppose to know that, though...! Heh..! Thanks.

Comment: @BobLeponge Yes! Definition of double integral is very helpful in such cases.

Comment: I'm sorry but, then, I'm still getting stuck with the right integral ((4-x^2)^(3/2)). Any particular strategy to integrate this? Wolfram Alpha solution is quite complex... Thanks.

Comment: Sure. You can use the trig substitution $x = 2\sin(\theta)$.